# Vote limit on your own questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting

I tend to up-vote users who answer my questions with reasonable answers as a norm for taking the time to actually post an answer. It is rare unless the answer is not relevant at all for me not to do this, however this sometimes means I reach my vote limit quite quickly.

Would it be possible to allow unlimited upvotes (one vote per answer) on questions asked by you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think part of the reason for the voting limit is to prevent one user from having too much influence over the system. Additionally, as a side effect, I believe it encourages user's to selective about what they upvote, so they don't be out of votes when they've found a really good question/answer. I don't disagree with your practice or policy, but I don't think the system needs to take further action to encourage or support this behavior.

Comment: Agreed. To an extent I also believe you should only up vote the most helpful or most correct answers. Hosting a pity party for everyone who simply took the time to post an answer undermines the meaning of rep.

Comment: Either a user will happily upvote all the good stuff he comes across (after all, the vote arrows' alt-text carry the definition: *useful*) and then run out of votes; the rest of the good stuff simply doesn't get upvoted by the user today; no big deal. Or a user only upvotes those posts that he feels are *really really* good and saves the remaining votes for equally good stuff; he might not use up his votes in a day; also no big deal. IMHO the latter approach is better, but both are good as long as only *useful* posts are upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Getting 30 answers in one day should be fairly unusual. You would have to post a lot of questions to get that many answers.

I guess your problem is that you've used all your votes on other answers and in that case you can just revisit your questions the next day and upvote the answers. I'm sorry, but I don't really see the problem that this feature would solve.

I think very few users would have any use for this feature at all.

Answer (score 0):

This was enacted soon after the Private-Beta period started. There was some disagreement at the time, but I believe most people have agreed that this is a good policy.